# Read entire physical file including file slack with python?

Tags: python

Is there a simple way to read all the allocated clusters of a given file with python? The usual python read() seemingly only allows me to read up to the logical size of the file (which is reasonable, of course), but I want to read all the clusters including slack space.

For example, I have a file called "test.bin" that is 1234 byte in logical size, but because my file system uses clusters of size 4096 bytes, the file has a physical size of 4096 bytes on disk. I.e., there are 2862 bytes in file slack space.

I'm not sure where to even start with this problem... I know I can read the raw disk from /dev/sda, but I'm not sure how to locate the clusters of interest... of course this is the whole point of having a file-system (to match up names of files to sectors on disk), but I don't know enough about how python interacts with the file-system to figure this out... yet... any help or pointers to references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And how should that behave with sparse files ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: To view the file slack, as specified in the question.

Comment: It looks like os.stat will give me the inode, but still not sure how to use this access the correct disk sector... If I can get just the starting sector on the disk that would be all I need....

Comment: But what is in there that you want to see?

Comment: _"s.stat will give me the inode"_ that is correct. _"I can get just the starting sector on the disk that would be all I need"_ only assuming you have extent-based file system and no fragmentation.

Comment: Scratch that, I guess I would need the last sector of each fragment... but I will settle for anything at this point. @PTBNL, what is it that you are getting at with your question, I'm not sure how it addresses my question. File slack is generally useful for computer forensics. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, do you know how I go from inode to starting sector in a pythonic way? I think debugfs will give it to me from the command line...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an ext2/3/4 filesytem, as you guess yourself, your best bet is probably to:

1. use a wrapper (like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem/source/browse/trunk/fs/wrapfs/debugfs.py?r=624)) around debugfs to get the list of blocks associated with a given file:

   ```
   debugfs:  blocks ./f.txt
   2562
   ```
2. to read-back that/those block(s) from the block device / image file

   ```
   >>> f = open('/tmp/test.img','rb')
   >>> f.seek(2562*4*1024)
   10493952
   >>> bytes = f.read(4*1024)
   >>> bytes
   b'Some data\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
   ...
   ```

Not very fancy but that will work. Please note you don't have to mount the FS to do any of these steps. This is especially important for forensic applications where you cannot trust in anyway the content of the disk and/or are not allowed per regulation to mount the disk image.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you for the answer. I'm trying to play with this on cygwin right now and debugfs is not playing along nicely... I'm going to mess with it later when I'm at home with my real linux machine...

Comment: @hft debugfs is for ext2/3/4 filesystem only. It _should_ work on cygwin if working on an _image_ of a _partition_ formated with that FS. I'm not sure this would work on an attached disk though.

Comment: I was just looking into how to create an ext2 partition on a file to play with in cygwin, looks like mke2fs will do it...

Comment: @hft Something _like_ that: `dd of='test.img' if=/dev/null bs=1M count=8`, then `mke2fs -F test.img`

Answer (score 0):

There is a C open source forensic tool that implements file access successfully.
Here is an overview of the tool [Link](https://www.computersecuritystudent.com/FORENSICS/HIDING/lesson1/index.html).
You can download it [here](http://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/linux/security/bmap-1.0.17.tar.gz).
It basically uses the **POSIX system call *open()*** that returns a raw file discriptor (integer) that you can use with the POSIX system calls *read()* and *write()* without the restrinction of stopping at EOF which stops you from accessing the file slack.

There are lots of examples online how to do a system call with python e.g. [this one](http://xahlee.info/perl-python/system_calls.html)